# Is there a better way to execute this code (load multiple urls)?

Tags: android, performance, arraylist, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

my code is working but when i launch the app, it is not fluent, i was wondering if there is a better way to make this code work or more cleaner to improve quickness ? Please any answer is welcome. Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<Articles> mArticlesList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private String[] mUrl = new String[]{"https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=buzzfeed&apiKey=5e08eafaefd44d14ad70ceea834c16bb"
            , "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-verge&apiKey=5e08eafaefd44d14ad70ceea834c16bb"
            , "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-lad-bible&apiKey=5e08eafaefd44d14ad70ceea834c16bb"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        for (int i = 0; i < mUrl.length; i++) {
            getInfos(mUrl[i]);
        }
    }

    private void getInfos(String url) {

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                            getMultipleUrls(jsonData);

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    getCurrentArticles(mArticlesList);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        }
                    });
                    alertUserAboutError();
                }
            });
        } else {
            alertUserAboutError();
        }

    }

    private void getMultipleUrls(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        if (mArticlesList == null) {
            mArticlesList = getArticleForecast(jsonData);
        } else {
            mArticlesList.addAll(getArticleForecast(jsonData));
        }
    }

    private void getCurrentArticles(List<Articles> articles) {

        ArticleAdapter articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(this, articles);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        alertDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }

    private List<Articles> getArticleForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray articles = forecast.getJSONArray("articles");

        List<Articles> listArticles = new ArrayList<>(articles.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonArticle = articles.getJSONObject(i);
            Articles article = new Articles();

            String urlImage = jsonArticle.getString("urlToImage");

            article.setTitle(jsonArticle.getString("title"));
            article.setDescription(jsonArticle.getString("description"));
            article.setImageView(urlImage);
            article.setArticleUrl(jsonArticle.getString("url"));

            listArticles.add(i, article);
        }

        return listArticles;
    }
```

Comment: you can't ask to review and improve your code here.

Comment: Why that ? It's the same that if i don't succeed something ? Should i name this : Slowness of my code ?
Don't get it...

Comment: `Why that ?` - that's because of SO rules. Have you put some affort investigating why it's slow by yourself? Have you rtried running some profiling? What exactly is slow? Network operations, or the code after you get response from server? If network operations, then obviously your internet/backend is slow, and you can do nothing about it. Also Do your network operations run one by one, or in parallel? You can do something with `OkHttpClient` to make them run in parallel.

Comment: Of course i tried several things i don't come here just to other people do my job, i just wanted some help but obviously this is not the right place.

Comment: Ignoring on topicness-  if you want help on performance, you have to tell us what isn't performing.  "It's slow" isn't a question we can answer.  What's slow?  Displaying the UI?  Performing some calculation?  Responding to user input?  Something else entirely?  We can't guess what you mean.

Comment: Ok, so my problem is that everytime that i call getInfos method i create a new client.. i guess that's my problem but i don't know how to do another way to get multiple urls..

Comment: @VladMatvienko is correct, though it may also be helpful to know that there is a place for this type of question. **StackOverflow** is meant for questions about a *specific* programming problem; they should be practical and answerable, as documented in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). While [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is meant for asking questions on how to improve a *working* piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ok, so my problem is that every time that I call `getInfos` method I
>   create a new client..

This is *exactly* your issue; and there are a few ways of solving it.

The *fastest* way to solve your issue is to just create the `OkHttpClient` in your `onCreate` method as a global variable. You may also want to only check if the network is available a single time.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String[] mUrls = new String[] {
        "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=buzzfeed&apiKey=5e08eafaefd44d14ad70ceea834c16bb",
        "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-verge&apiKey=5e08eafaefd44d14ad70ceea834c16bb",
        "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-lad-bible&apiKey=5e08eafaefd44d14ad70ceea834c16bb"
    };

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient;
    private ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            for (String url : mUrls) {
                createRequest(url);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createRequest(String url) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        mOkHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                // Your response implementation
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException exception) {
                // Your failure implementation
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        NetworkInfo info = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return info != null && info.isConnected();
    }

}
```

An even more beneficial way to solve this issue (if you use OkHttp in more than one `Activity`) is to only create a single `OkHttpClient` for your entire application. Though, this will require dependency injection, which the Android framework can make a bit more complicated; [this is a good article](https://tech.just-eat.com/2015/10/26/dependency-injection-on-android/) that covers the basics.

---

Also, to make your life even easier, I would recommend a few other libraries that compliment OkHttp. It may take a while to learn some of them, but each will make working with network code significantly easier on Android. You don't need all of them either, you can start with one and work up from there.

- [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) builds upon OkHttp (it is also by [Square](http://square.github.io/)), and
  makes interacting with APIs a breeze.
- [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) is a JSON parser (also by Square), that works with
  Retrofit so you can avoid the cumbersome `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`
  code (Google's [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) also works with Retrofit).
- And finally; [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) and [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) will make asynchronous
  calls even easier; you can even [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) all three of your requests
  together, so you receive the results all at once!