# RecyclerView reload same data when refresh

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, loader, swiperefreshlayout

I have a problem, when i swipe to refresh the data, the first swipe is ok but after that every swipe reload and add the same data over and over again, by the end i have a list with same items over and over... I'm using a loader.
I tried to clear before but i don't understand what's wrong with my code, if someone could explain it to me. Thank You.

Here my code :

```
public abstract class NewsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Articles>> {

    protected ItemAdapter mArticleAdapter;
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected NewsFragment.OnNewSelectedInterface mListener;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mManager;
    protected SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    protected LoaderManager mLoaderManager;
    private boolean mStateSaved;

    private static final int NEWS_LOAD_ID = 1;
    public static final String KEY_LIST = "key_list";

    public interface OnNewSelectedInterface {
        void onListNewSelected(int index, ArrayList<Articles> articles);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_present_news, container, false);

        mListener = (NewsFragment.OnNewSelectedInterface) getActivity();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mArticleAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Articles>(), mListener);
        mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        mStateSaved = mArticleAdapter.isStateSaved();

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        getData();
        refreshData();

        if(!isNetworkAvailable())alertUserAboutError();

        setDivider();

        return view;
    }

    private void setDivider() {
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView
                .getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    }

    private void getData() {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(NEWS_LOAD_ID, null, this).forceLoad();
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        alertDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }

    protected abstract String[] getUrl();

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void refreshData() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mArticleAdapter.clear();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        });

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<ArrayList<Articles>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new NewsLoader(getActivity(), getUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Articles>> loader, ArrayList<Articles> data) {
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            mArticleAdapter.addAll(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<Articles>> loader) {
        mArticleAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

My loader class :

```
public class NewsLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<Articles>>{

    private ArrayList<Articles> mArticlesArrayList;
    private String[] mUrl;

    public NewsLoader(Context context, String[] url) {
        super(context);
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Articles> loadInBackground() {

        OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient();
        for (String aMUrl : mUrl) {
            Request mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(aMUrl).build();
            try {
                Response response = mClient.newCall(mRequest).execute();
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String json = response.body().string();
                        getMultipleUrls(json);
                    }
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return mArticlesArrayList;
    }

    private void getMultipleUrls(String jsonData) throws JSONException {

        if (mArticlesArrayList == null) {
            mArticlesArrayList = getArticleForecast(jsonData);
        } else {
            mArticlesArrayList.addAll(getArticleForecast(jsonData));
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Articles> getArticleForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray articles = forecast.getJSONArray("articles");

        ArrayList<Articles> listArticles = new ArrayList<>(articles.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonArticle = articles.getJSONObject(i);
            Articles article = new Articles();

            String urlImage = jsonArticle.getString("urlToImage");

            article.setTitle(jsonArticle.getString("title"));
            article.setDescription(jsonArticle.getString("description"));
            article.setImageView(urlImage);
            article.setArticleUrl(jsonArticle.getString("url"));

            listArticles.add(i, article);
        }

        return listArticles;
    }
}
```

My Adapter class :

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ArticleViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAGO = ItemAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private final NewsFragment.OnNewSelectedInterface mListener;
    private ArrayList<Articles> mArticlesList;
    private Context mContext;
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private boolean mStateSaved = false;


    public boolean isStateSaved() {
        return mStateSaved;
    }

    public void setStateSaved(boolean stateSaved) {
        mStateSaved = stateSaved;
    }

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Articles> articles, NewsFragment.OnNewSelectedInterface listener){
        mContext = context;
        mArticlesList = articles;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card_view, parent, false);

        ArticleViewHolder articleViewHolder = new ArticleViewHolder(view);
        articleViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        return articleViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.bindArticle(mArticlesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        setAnimation(holder.itemView, holder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(viewToAnimate.getContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArticlesList.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mArticlesList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<Articles> articles) {
        mArticlesList.addAll(articles);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    protected class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        private ImageView mImageView;
        private TextView mTitleTextView, mDescriptionTextView;
        private FloatingActionButton mSaveButton;

        private ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleWithoutImage);
            mDescriptionTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
            mSaveButton = (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        private void bindArticle(final Articles article) {

            Glide.with(mContext).load(article.getImageView()).into(mImageView);
            mTitleTextView.setText(article.getTitle());
            mDescriptionTextView.setText(article.getDescription());
            if(mDescriptionTextView.getText().equals("")){
                mDescriptionTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    insertArticle(article);
                    article.setStateSaved(true);
                }
            });

            Log.v(TAGO, "Item id : " + getItemId()
                    + "Item count : " + getItemCount()
                    + "Item position : " + getAdapterPosition()
                    + String.valueOf(article.isStateSaved()));
        }

        private void insertArticle(Articles articles) {

            String title = articles.getTitle();
            String description = articles.getDescription();
            String url = articles.getArticleUrl();

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(ArticleContract.ArticleEntry.COLUMN_TITLE_ARTICLE, title);
            contentValues.put(ArticleContract.ArticleEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE, description);
            contentValues.put(ArticleContract.ArticleEntry.COLUMN_URL_ARTICLE, url);

            Uri uri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(ArticleContract.ArticleEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

            if(uri == null) {
                Log.v(TAGO, "Error");
            } else Toast.makeText(mContext, "Article Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onListNewSelected(getLayoutPosition(), mArticlesList);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your `SwipeRefreshLayout` does anything. The `onRefresh()` method only calls `mArticleAdapter.clear()` and `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)`; how are you actually attempting to reload the data?

Comment: Sorry, when trying to fix the bug I remove one line, I call getData() ; right after clear the list in my refresh method

Comment: Is each `Articles` object a multiple "articles"? If not, shouldn't the class be titled `Article`? Not a big issue, just a confusing word choice.

Comment: Yeah it should but it doesn't solve my problem..

Comment: Have you checked your api whether it is giving you redundant data?

Comment: Why are you using `ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition` instead of the position provided by `onBindViewHolder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ViewHolder#setIsRecyclable` incorrectly; this method is meant to be used to prevent a `ViewHolder` from being recycled *only* while changes are being made to it. According to the documentation:

> Calls to `setIsRecyclable()` should always be paired (one call to
>   `setIsRecyclabe(false)` should always be matched with a later call to
>   `setIsRecyclable(true)`).

This means none of your `ViewHolder` objects will be recycled, effectively making the use of a `RecyclerView` worthless, and preventing it from reusing the views when you attempt to bind new objects to your `RecyclerView`.

So, in short, remove that line of code.

---

I noticed a few other small issues with your adapter code as well, which can cause a multitude headaches in the future; so I took the liberty of highlighting some of the changes I would make.

Just for my own sanity, I will refer to your `Articles` class as `Article`.

It is usually not a good idea to pass around your `Context` all over the place. The `View` passed to your `ViewHolder` already has a reference to a `Context`, so you can use that instead.

As for the `insertArticle()` code, the `Activity` should be handling this anyway. So you can pass the `Article` back to the `Activity` by passing a listener to your `Adapter` (and subsequently, each `ViewHolder`) instead of the `Context`.

You should also consider using the [`DiffUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) class instead of just calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`; it is much more efficient. Just make sure your `Article` class is implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()` or it will not work.

I didn't include the animation code (that can easily be added back in) or the saved state code (mostly because I don't know what you were trying to do).

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Article> {

    private List<Article> mData;

    private ArticleViewHolder.OnSelectedListener mOnSelectedListener;
    private ArticleViewHolder.OnSaveListener mOnSaveListener;

    public ArticleAdapter(ArticleViewHolder.OnSelectedListener onSelectedListener, ArticleViewHolder.OnSaveListener onSaveListener) {
        mOnSelectedListener = onSelectedListener;
        mOnSaveListener = onSaveListener;
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void replaceData(final List<Article> data) {
        final List<Article> oldData = new ArrayList<>(mData);
        mData.clear();

        if (data != null) {
            mData.addAll(data);
        }

        DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtil.Callback() {
            @Override
            public int getOldListSize() {
                return oldData.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getNewListSize() {
                return mData.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return oldData.get(oldItemPosition).equals(mData.get(newItemPosition));
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return oldData.get(oldItemPosition).equals(mData.get(newItemPosition));
            }
        }).dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }

    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card_view, parent, false);
        return new SelectLocationViewHolder(view, mOnSelectedListener, mOnSaveListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(mData.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

}
```

---

```
public class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public interface OnSelectedListener {
        void onSelected(Article article);
    }

    public interface OnSaveListener {
        void onSave(Article article);
    }

    private View mView;
    private Article mArticle;

    private OnSelectedListener mOnSelectedListener;
    private OnSaveListener mOnSaveListener;

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mTitleTextView, mDescriptionTextView;
    private FloatingActionButton mSaveButton;

    public ArticleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnSelectedListener onSelectedListener, final OnSaveListener onSaveListener) {
        super(itemView);

        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleWithoutImage);
        mDescriptionTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
        mSaveButton = (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

        mView = itemView;
        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onSelectedListener.onSelected(mArticle);
            }
        });

        mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onSaveListener.onSave(mArticle);
            }
        });
    }

    public void bind(Article article) {
        mArticle = article;
        mTitleTextView.setText(article.getTitle());

        mDescriptionTextView.setText(article.getDescription());
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(article.getDescription())) {
            mDescriptionTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Glide.with(mView.getContext()).load(article.getImage()).into(mImageView);
    }

}
```

---

#### Edit

The actual issue is that your loader uses the same `ArrayList` every time, and keeps adding the new results to it.

```
public class NewsLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Article>> {

    private final String[] mUrls;
    private final OkHttpClient mClient;

    public NewsLoader(Context context, OkHttpClient client, String... urls) {
        super(context);
        mClient = client;
        mUrls = urls;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Article> loadInBackground() {
        List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String url : mUrls) {
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
            try {
                Response response = mClient.newCall(request).execute();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    parseData(response.body().string(), articles);
                }
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

         return articles;
    }

    private void parseData(List<Article> articles, String data) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray a = forecast.getJSONArray("articles");

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject o = a.getJSONObject(i);
            Article article = new Article(
                    o.getString("title"),
                    o.getString("description"),
                    o.getString("url"),
                    o.getString("urlToImage"));
            articles.add(article);
        }
    }

}
```

Also, you may have noticed, I made a small change to your `Article` constructor. You should consider making the `Article` class [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html), as this will prevent you from making mistakes when dealing with multithreading. It should look something like this:

```
public class Article {

    private final String mTitle;
    private final String mDescription;
    private final String mUrl;
    private final String mImageUrl;


    public Article(String title, String description, String url, String imageUrl) {
        mTitle = title;
        mDescription = description;
        mUrl = url;
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String title() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String description() {
        return mDescription;
    }

    public String url() {
        return mUrl;
    }

    public String imageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Article other = (Article) o;

        return mTitle != null && mTitle.equals(other.mTitle) &&
                mDescription != null && mDescription.equals(other.mDescription) &&
                mUrl != null && mUrl.equals(other.mUrl) &&
                mImageUrl != null && mImageUrl.equals(other.mImageUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = mTitle != null ? mTitle.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (mDescription != null ? mDescription.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (mUrl != null ? mUrl.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (mImageUrl != null ? mImageUrl.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I ll try that as soon as possible and thank you for taking the time to review my code! I'll let you know!!

Comment: Also like I asked below could you please tell me if there's is a better way to insert data without looping through my url..? Thanks

Comment: @samuelzaffran I'm guessing you are talking about your previous question; "[Is there a better way to execute this code (load multiple urls)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227239/is-there-a-better-way-to-execute-this-code-load-multiple-urls)"? If that is the case, you should [provide link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) in the future; it won't always be so easy to figure out which question you are referring to.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know ! But i tried to remove the line of code, but still.. i have always more data over and over each time i swipe..

Comment: @samuelzaffran Huh, nothing else stands out as problematic, other than possibly the use of `ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition`. Try replacing your `Adapter` with the code I posted above, if you are still having the same issue it could have something to do with your network code.

Comment: i solved it by calling restart loader, instead of init, it seems that when i call init, the loader is not recreated and the data are still present, so i also could clear the data in the loader onFinished method but it felt better to call restart. What do you think ?

Comment: @samuelzaffran Ah, I see the issue. You keep the same `mArticleArrayList` for each call to `loadInBackground()`. You can fix this by making the list a local variable, I will make an edit to my answer.

Comment: @samuelzaffran You are very welcome. If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: i would but can't i don't have enough reputation they told to me, the soonest i can, the soonest i'll do it !

Comment: @samuelzaffran I think you are confusing up-voting and accepting. You cannot up-vote until you reach 15 reputation, but you can always accept an answer by clicking the gray checkmark underneath the up and down arrows (you actually gain reputation from doing this as well).

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindArticle(mArticlesList.get(position));
    setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
}


public void addAll(ArrayList<Articles> articles) {
    mArticlesList.clear();
    mArticlesList.addAll(articles);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If this doesn't wrok then I think your api is giving you redundant data. 
Why you are using `articleViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);`

One another place which might cause the problem is

```
private void getMultipleUrls(String jsonData) throws JSONException {

    if (mArticlesArrayList == null) {
         mArticlesArrayList = getArticleForecast(jsonData);
    } else {
        mArticlesArrayList.addAll(getArticleForecast(jsonData));
    }
}
```

You are calling it from a loop add adding data to your arraylist. There somehow multiple data can be inserted in your `ArrayList`

Comment: Nope my api doesn't give me redundant data, I call recyclable false cause when I swipe to refresh the order of my data change! Can you please tell me how to insert without looping? I searched but didn't find something that worked.. Thanks

Comment: First you need to be sure of whether that method is putting redundant  data into the list.

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't I have an array of url (String) and every URL, is sending me some articles but they're unique every one of them