# Synchronous Call in Fragment didn't run at first launch and get error data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using OkHttp to get HTML string and list the information in RecyclerView in a fragment.

However, when the app runs, it didn't show list information at first launch.

After I click other fragment page and  go back to this fragment page, it show list.

But when I swipe down to see more list, the list repeat for twice (or more?) and the item background color disordered.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

My Adapter

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<NewsModel> mNewsList;
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView newsNameText;
        TextView newsDataText;
        View listView;
        public ViewHolder(View newsView) {
            super(newsView);
            newsNameText = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_Name);
            newsDataText = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_Data);
            listView = newsView;
        }
    }
    public NewsAdapter(List<NewsModel> newsList) {
        mNewsList = newsList;
    }
    @Override
    public  ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }
    public void setData(List<NewsModel> viewData) {
        mNewsList.clear();
        mNewsList.addAll(viewData);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NewsModel news = mNewsList.get(position);
        holder.setIsRecyclable(true);
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            holder.listView.setBackgroundColor(0x80E0EEEE);
        }
        holder.newsNameText.setText(news.getName());
        holder.newsDataText.setText(news.getData());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNewsList.size();
    }

}
```

My fragment

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
    List<NewsModel> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<NewsModel> htmlList = new ArrayList<>();
    NewsAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View newsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
        RecyclerView newsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        newsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(getNews());
        newsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return newsView;

    }
    private List<NewsModel> getNews() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url("http://www.career.fudan.edu.cn/jsp/career_talk_list.jsp?count=50&list=true")
                            .build();
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String resultString = response.body().string();
                    resultList.clear();
                    resultList.addAll(getResult(resultString));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    /*new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            adapter.setData(resultList);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });//postdelayed (runnable long) cannot be applied to runnable*/
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return resultList;
    }

    private List<NewsModel> getResult(final String response) {
        XXXXXX
        return htmlList;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, Okhttp should not be ran in a Thread like this. Use `client.newCall(request).enqueue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that maybe you are adding many entries and since recyclerview is trying to reuse those views instead of redrawing again and again which cause sometimes view inconsistency. Here is the problem [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498740/recyclerview-reload-same-data-when-refresh) Look into it if you are having the same problem. 
to disable it or enable it to use in your **bindViewHolder(**)

`setIsRecyclable(Boolean enable)`

And your second problem is that **onCreateView()** is called the second time when coming back from another fragment causing addition of duplicate data again so you need to clear the list before adding any new entries and Why it's not showing in the first run because you have added data in another thread and did not updated the adapter about it.

```
List<NewsModel> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
NewsAdapter adapter ;
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View newsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
    RecyclerView newsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    newsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new NewsAdapter(resultList);
    newsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    getNews();
    return newsView;
}

   private void getNews(){
        AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(final Void... voids) {
                String resultString = null;
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://www.career.fudan.edu.cn/jsp/career_talk_list.jsp?count=50&list=true")
                        .build();
                Response response = null;
                try {
                    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    resultString = response.body().string();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return resultString;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final String resultString) {
                super.onPostExecute(resultString);
                resultList.clear();
                resultList.addAll(getResult(resultString));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your method. But the list turns out to be blank......whatever I tried.

Comment: hi@AlexLi the reason for the empty list was that I forgot to call getNews() in onCreateView(). So you can check now I have updated my answer and also included an async task for loading news data which is better than what we were doing previously.

Comment: update your getNews() accordingly and call getNews() in onCreatView() to see the change. let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: It is much better. Still one problem:when I swipe down to see more list, the list color disordered.

Comment: In my onBIndViewHolder, I use  "if(position % 2 == 0){
            holder.listView.setBackgroundColor(0x80E0EEEE)};"

Comment: @Alex you do not need an Asynctask with Okhttp. There's a full example here. https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AsynchronousGet.java

Answer (score 0):

The thread will change the resultList in some delay, but you already passed old data before that.
Please try as following...

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View newsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
    RecyclerView newsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    newsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    getNews(newsRecyclerView);
    return newsView;
}

private void getNews(final RecyclerView newsRecyclerView){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://www.career.fudan.edu.cn/jsp/career_talk_list.jsp?count=50&list=true")
                        .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String resultString = response.body().string();
                List<NewsModel> resultList = getResult(resultString);
                NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(resultList);
                newsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private List<NewsModel> getResult(final String response) {
    XXXXXXXXX
    return List;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main pattern is bad.
The easiest way for this code is to set (not add) items in adapter when it is downloaded and invoke on adapter notifyDataSetChanged() - all cells will be redraw.

So make adapter as field, add method to adapter setData() and:

```
...
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
String resultString = response.body().string();
resultList = getResult(resultString);
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.setData(results);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't need a separate setData method. This answer is the builtin pattern. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610769/2308683

Comment: @mac229 new Handler Alerted: postdelayed (runnable long) cannot be applied to runnable

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried vikas's method. The list is empty.